# in node i am cros not working for cross-platfrom

Tags: node.js, express, cross-platform

I have used cros library
as

```
const cros = require('cros')
const app = require('express')
app.use(cros())
```

but I am not able to use it in cross server I am only able to use it in my system only what is the way that I can access the API in my another server by running backend in system

Comment: Isn't it `CORS`? **Cross Origin Resource Sharing**

Answer (score 0):

If it is about cross origin resource sharing thing you're trying to do then use:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```